# Run Script before load balancer connection

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

Alright, so I figure I will ask the awesome stackoverflow community to see if I can get an answer.

My question is, I want to run a script, php specifically but I could do any type technically whenever a connection comes into haproxy. I can chnage my load balancing software if needed or use a non load balancing software too.

Order of events

- Connection attempt via haproxy
- haproxy sees that it is a certain port/port range
- haproxy triggers script
- haproxy forwards connection like it is supposed to.

How could this be possible? Also the script needs to trigger before it forwards the traffic

I figure someone will ask, so I will explain in advance. I have an online game, but I don't want it running all the time. If someone tries to connect it starts the game via an api/script.

Update *****
I was thinking about the logic. What you could do is set a service to listen for these ports on the game server and then when it sees a connection run the script that shutsdown the listener and starts the game but you would want to automatically restart the listener if the game shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand your logic...why you are wanted to do so....

Following are URL show how you can configure HAproxy to trigger a xinetd script. I understand this is really something you want , but least it will gives you clues for exact solution.

http://sysbible.org/2008/12/04/having-haproxy-check-mysql-status-through-a-xinetd-script/